# A well-known sines limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The following question is related to the answer i've found for this limit and i like to know if it's valid. I need to find the following limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin(kx)}{x} $$
where k is a fixed positive integer.

Proof:

Here we'are going to appeal to a very well known inequality:

$$ \sin(x) < x < \tan(x),\space 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Then we have that:

$$ \sin(kx) < kx < \tan(kx),\space 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2k}$$

From the above inequality we get that: 
$$\cos(kx) < \frac{\sin(kx)}{kx}< 1$$
After multiplying the inequality by k and taking the limit when x goes to ${0}$ we get that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\space k\cos(kx) < \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(kx)}{x}< k$$

By Squeeze Theorem the limit is $k$.

For such an answer i received a downvote because in the last inequality i used $"<"$ instead of $"\leq"$. I'd like to know your opinion and if i'm wrong then i want to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143473/finding-lim-limits-x-to-0-frac-sin3xx

Comment: The hypotheses of the squeeze theorem are still satisfied, as a<b<c implies a≤b≤c. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I don't have any problem with your solution except for it being beyond the OP's level of math, which is why I did not upvote it. Also, this may better be suited for Meta.

Comment: I have no problem with using $"\leq"$ but i only want to know which way is the correct way for avoiding future discussions on this topic.

Comment: It often seems like a really tiny point, but the thing to remember is that the correct deduction when taking limits is to go from $u_n < w_n$ to $\lim u_n \leq \lim w_n$ - then nobody can quibble with it! (Took me a long time to learn to be that precise!).

Comment: I think the point is correct: it ***must*** be weak inequalities at the end, not sharp ones. Yet I would never downvote an answer for that. I think such a thing is petty and uncalled for. A simple comment after the answer would do it, perhaps with a little edit.

Comment: I would agree - a downvote rather than a comment seems pretty harsh to me, and less instructive.

Comment: In fact, the problem is not a downvote, but the correct way i need to follow further. At school i used "<" instead of $"\leq"$. I've also found a short movie on this subject on khanacademy: http://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/v/proof--lim--sin-x--x. In the movie it is used "<" instead of $"\leq"$.

Comment: Khan isn't really being rigorous there. $a<b<c$ can never end up at $a=b=c$, which is the whole point of the squeeze theorem. Trichotomy and all that.

Comment: One of my colleagues said that there is some obvious difference between some limits. For instance, when x tends to $\infty$ of $\frac{1}{x}$ the limit is something the function never reaches. But if you take $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ when x tends to 0 then the function reaches its limit and pass through it.

Comment: Or it's better to say it is connected to it than passing. {regarding to sin(x)/x}. i can't explain better than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*technically* I see why the downvote happened: the whole point of the squeeze theorem is that the 'outer' functions are equal at that point. Using strict inequalities means the squeeze theorem wouldn't work. It's a nitpicky point, but such is math I guess. For the record I think it would have been more constructive just to post a comment rather than downvote with a correction that minor.

Comment: The hypotheses of the squeeze theorem are still satisfied, as $a<b<c$ implies $a\le b \le c$. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: If $a<b<c$, then $a=c \implies a=b=c$ is an impossibility, since you're explicitly saying that $a$ is strictly less than $c$. $a<b<c$ does imply $a\leq b\leq c$, yes, but never $a=b=c$, which is the conclusion the squeeze theorem needs to come to.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is this: we have to be very careful with inequalities when we take limits. For example, for $n \ge 1$, we obviously have $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$, but when we let $n\to\infty$, we can only conclude that $\lim\frac{1}{n+1} \le \lim\frac{1}{n}$ and not $\lim\frac{1}{n+1} < \lim\frac{1}{n}$, since both limits are clearly zero.

Comment: He's not concluding any strict inequalities, only equality, so there is no problem.

Comment: But if you read his solution, he takes limits and still has strict inequalities in the line including the limits - they really should be $\le$ - a bit nit-picky, but to be precise, his reasoning is at fault.